# Extract each column sequentially from a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a list of matrices each with the same number of columns.  I'd like to create a single data frame with the first column from matrix1 followed by the first column from matrix2 followed by the first column from matrix3...then the second column from matrix1 followed by the second column from matrix2, etc.

```
counts <- data.frame(apples=round(rnorm(10, mean=5), digits=0),
                     oranges=round(rnorm(10, mean=5), digits=0),
                     pears=round(rnorm(10, mean=5), digits=0))
weights <- data.frame(apples=round(rnorm(10, mean=3), digits=1),
                      oranges=round(rnorm(10, mean=3), digits=1),
                      pears=round(rnorm(10, mean=3), digits=1))
diameters <- data.frame(apples=round(rnorm(10, mean=10), digits=1),
                      oranges=round(rnorm(10, mean=10), digits=1),
                      pears=round(rnorm(10, mean=10), digits=1))

fruitdata <- list(counts, weights, diameters)

> fruitdata
[[1]]
   apples oranges pears
1       4       4     4
2       6       5     5
3       6       4     6
4       6       5     4
5       7       4     5
6       6       7     5
7       4       6     5
8       4       6     5
9       4       5     5
10      5       7     5

[[2]]
   apples oranges pears
1     2.5     3.1   1.1
2     4.3     2.4   4.2
3     2.8     3.5   1.3
4     2.8     1.5   2.5
5     2.9     3.3   1.9
6     3.7     1.5   2.2
7     2.9     2.7   5.1
8     3.0     2.5   3.0
9     2.3     2.3   1.7
10    2.7     2.9   1.4

[[3]]
   apples oranges pears
1    10.5    10.4  12.3
2    10.0     9.8  10.1
3     9.7    11.1  10.5
4     9.1    10.9   9.9
5     8.5     9.4   9.7
6     8.9    12.2  10.0
7    11.0     9.7  10.8
8     9.4     8.6  12.1
9     8.6     9.9  11.0
10   11.9    10.2  11.2
```

What I want is something like this...

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    4  2.5 10.5    4  3.1 10.4
 [2,]    6  4.3 10.0    5  2.4  9.8
 [3,]    6  2.8  9.7    4  3.5 11.1
 [4,]    6  2.8  9.1    5  1.5 10.9
 [5,]    7  2.9  8.5    4  3.3  9.4
 [6,]    6  3.7  8.9    7  1.5 12.2
 [7,]    4  2.9 11.0    6  2.7  9.7
 [8,]    4  3.0  9.4    6  2.5  8.6
 [9,]    4  2.3  8.6    5  2.3  9.9
[10,]    5  2.7 11.9    7  2.9 10.2
```

I can use sapply to pull the first column from each matrix:

```
test1 <- sapply(fruitdata, function(x) x[,1])

> test1
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    4  2.5 10.5
 [2,]    6  4.3 10.0
 [3,]    6  2.8  9.7
 [4,]    6  2.8  9.1
 [5,]    7  2.9  8.5
 [6,]    6  3.7  8.9
 [7,]    4  2.9 11.0
 [8,]    4  3.0  9.4
 [9,]    4  2.3  8.6
[10,]    5  2.7 11.9
```

So I tried:

```
test2 <- sapply(fruitdata, function(x) x[,1:ncol(fruitdata[[1]])])
```

But it did not get me what I wanted.

```
>test2

        [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      
apples  Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Numeric,10
oranges Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Numeric,10
pears   Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Numeric,10
```

I can, of course, write a for loop to do this task, but it seems like I should be able to do it with the apply or plyr suites instead, but I can't quite figure out how to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: incorporated rawr's clever suggestion.

Is this what you want?

```
do.call(cbind, fruitdata)[order(rep(1:3, 3))]

#    apples apples.1 apples.2 oranges oranges.1 oranges.2 pears pears.1 pears.2
# 1       4      3.2     10.1       6       4.9      10.0     4     2.6    10.8
# 2       6      4.3     10.0       4       4.2       8.4     4     3.7     9.4
# 3       5      2.9      9.4       4       4.4       8.7     5     5.5     9.2
# 4       6      2.8     12.6       6       1.9      10.4     5     1.9    11.0
# 5       8      3.6      9.5       6       3.8       9.7     4     3.7     8.9
# 6       4      4.3     10.1       4       2.3       9.7     5     4.1    10.5
# 7       5      2.1     10.2       4       3.2       8.7     6     0.9    10.6
# 8       4      4.2      9.8       7       5.0      10.0     5     2.0     9.2
# 9       4      4.1     10.5       6       1.8       8.2     6     3.2     9.1
# 10      6      2.4      9.3       5       3.1       8.6     4     3.6    10.5
```

Here, we just stick all the matrices together, and then re-order the columns so that they end up how you want.

Comment: clever, brodieg, clever

Comment: you could get it with `do.call(cbind, fruitdata)[order(rep(1:3, 3))]`, what is the 1:9 part for?

Comment: @TaliaYoung, if this answers your question, please consider marking it as such.  Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know I was supposed to - did I do it right?